# RVM on Mac .... .... ....?

Tags: macos, rvm

I want to run Jeckyll on Mac.

It says I need gem.

So I try to get RVM to manage ruby.

https://rvm.io/rvm/security

```
Garretts-MBP:~ garrettsmith$ which gpg
Garretts-MBP:~ garrettsmith$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
-bash: gpg: command not found
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need GPG/PGP. You could use something like the suite provided via https://gpgtools.org/. Alternatively, you should be able to install it via homebrew. I believe it's `brew install gnupg`.